# function is not executing on li click in angular6?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I am building custom autocomplete like drop down using angular7. I have this `html` in my `component.html`

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="text here" (keyup)="credentialsSearchFilter($event)" (blur)="hideList()" [(ngModel)]="nameDisplayModel">
  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-2" *ngIf="records.length > 0">
        <ul class="suggestion-list">
            <li *ngFor="let record of records" (click)="getNameValue(record)">{{record.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in `component.ts` i have this code

```js
records = [];
  selectedName : string = '';
  nameDisplayModel = '';
  users = [
    {name : 'Fahad', value :'fahad'},
    {name : 'Saad', value :'saad'},
    {name : 'Anus', value :'anus'},
    {name : 'Hazik', value :'hazik'},
    {name : 'Ahsan', value :'ahsan'},
    {name : 'Sohaib', value :'sohaib'}
  ]

  
  credentialsSearchFilter(event: any) {
    const val = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    this.records = this.users.filter(function(d) {
      return d.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val;
    });
  }
  hideList(){
    this.records = [];
  }
  getNameValue(row){
      console.log('hello')
      this.nameDisplayModel = row.name;
      this.users.forEach(item=>{
        if(item.name === row.name){
          this.selectedName = row.value;
        }
      })
      this.records = [];
      console.log(this.selectedName)
  }
```

Now i am facing 3 issues.

Issue-01
On `li` i want to execute `getNameValue` function which is not executing right now and i don't know why it's not executing.

Issue-02
in the `ul` below the input box when i hover on li so hover css is not applying on whole `li`. It only applies only the small portion of li. But i want to make hover effect on whole li element.

Issue-03
When i type anything in `input` so when ul displays so width of ul that shows on typing in `input` should be in equal width as of input box.

You can see all these 3 issues in live `Stackblitz link` 
[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-me74sn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The `blur` event is executed before `click`

Solution: use mousedown event instead of click

2) You need to remove padding on your ul element and apply them to `li` element

3) You can make ul element absolutely positioned. This way it's easier to make the width of ul element to be equal width of the wrapped box with relative position.

**html**

```
<div class="autocomplete">
  <input type="text" ...>
  <ul *ngIf="records.length > 0" class="suggestion-list">
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
}
.suggestion-list{
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  ...
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vsgtny?file=src/app/app.component.css)**

Answer (score 0):

Regarding issue #1

You are never clicking on the `li` because you are hiding it before that. Why? Because on `(blur)` you are removing the array of records, and therefore the `ul` element is disappearing. Check this [fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h9xhss) of your project.

You have to find your own way of preventing this from happening. The basic idea is:

- If you click outside of the input field, and not in the list, hide
  the list.
- If you click outside of the input field, but it's in the
  list, perform your action and then hide the list.

I'd solve it with some variable that flags whether the user clicked on the list or not when the input was blurred.

Regarding issue #2

That's pure CSS. You're applying the CSS effects on hover on the entire `li`, it's just that the `ul` element has `padding`. You can solve that removing the `padding` from the `ul` and adding it to the `li`, for example, but there are many other ways.

Regarding issue #3

Seems to be purely a CSS question too. I'd put them with the same parent container and give them a width of 100%, but there are dozens of ways to solve it.

Comment: but i also want that if user click on input and never type anything and now user wants to close the drop down list so how can i manage that ?

Comment: I added some more info. I would suggest opening a different question for each different issue, otherwise, it becomes messy and quite irrelevant for everyone else.